# Comment s'écrit « si il l'avait su » ?

Tags: orthographe, conjonctions, élision

J'ai un gros doute sur l'écriture de :

> Comme si il l'avait toujours su.

Il me semble que « si il » devrait se contracter en « s'il » ce qui donnerait :

> Comme s'il l'avait toujours su.

qui, pourtant, me parait sonner faux car il y a deux contractions à la suite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de questions à se poser : lorsque si est suivi par "il" ou "ils", il est toujours remplacé par s'. On appelle cette règle l'élision.

Ici, la phrase correcte est donc :

> Comme s'il l'avait toujours su

Comment: L'exemple le plus parlant est "s'il vous plaît" :)

Comment: Ce qui me gêne c'est la double contraction "Si il" + "le avait" à la suite

Comment: Ce qui est sûr, c'est que "si il" et "le avait" ne sont jamais corrects, quel que soit le contexte. La seule possibilité est "s'il l'avait", ce qui me paraît tout à fait correct, phonétiquement et grammaticalement.

Comment: @ChristopherG. "Si il" est possible, si l'on veut insister sur "si". "le avait" en revanche est toujours incorrect. "Comme si il" paraît incorrect, lui.

Comment: @Froggiz Ainsi que dit par Christopher dans sa réponse, il s'agit d'[élisions](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89lision) (absorption d'une voyelle par une autre) et non de contractions au sens anglais du terme (où on a le choix entre _do not_ et _don't_). Ici, pas de liberté : il faut éviter le [hiatus](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hiatus). Il ne viendrait jamais à l'idée de parler de « le arbre ». Même chose ici (hormis le cas exceptionnel cité par Guillaume qui ne me semble valide qu'à l'oral).

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina - ***Comme si il*** https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comme+si+il%2Ccomme+s%27il&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomme%20si%20il%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccomme%20s%27il%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcomme%20s%27il%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BComme%20s%27il%3B%2Cc0 n'est pas incorrect en soi, c'est une tournure qui nécessite une courte pause entre les deux `i` à l'oral pour marquer l'insistance de la comparaison

Comment: Il suffit de faire un ngram avec « [comme si il](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comme%20si%20il&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomme%20si%20il%3B%2Cc0) » pour voir que bien sûr il faut se poser la question !

Answer (score 3):

> *Si il* venait à casser les disques. (Vian)
>  Comme *si il* ne savait pas dicter un acte. (Stendhal)

Leur choix ne repose sur aucune justification<sup>1</sup> apparente que la liberté. Par ailleurs, même si en français moderne il y a [élision](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1737) avec *si* devant le pronom *il/ils*, il faut toujours se poser des questions, par exemple sur le *registre* (**populaire**) désiré...

> Y demande *si y* doit commencer par l'évier ou les vatères du couloir.
>   (B. et Fl. [Groult](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beno%C3%AEte_Groult))
>   Ils se relevaient *si ils* voulaient. (Céline)

...ou la fonction grammaticale du mot, puisqu'on n'aura jamais élision avec l'adverbe (*il est si illustre*) : l'élision est donc restreinte ici à la **conjonction de subordination** comme dans les exemples précédents.

---

Cette liberté étayée (qu'on n'a pas avec le pronom *le* placé devant le verbe), on en observe maintenant les conséquences :

> (1) Comme si il l'avait mangé.
>  (2) Comme s'il l'avait mangé.
>  (3) Comme si
>   il avait mangé [sans objet direct].
>  (4) Comme s'il avait mangé [sans objet direct].

En explorant les combinaisons, on voit que sans élision, on sent peut-être plus clairement la présence ou l'absence de l'objet direct. C'est qu'on ne peut tronquer le double son [*l*] ici si on doit faire ressortir le pronom objet direct, et donc on lutte contre un phénomène similaire à l'[*haplologie*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplologie) (amenuisement de phonèmes répétés ; c'est peut-être ce réflexe qui fait qu'on trouve désagréable les « deux contractions à la suite » comme on dit). Par ailleurs, certains locuteurs peuvent ne plus savoir à l'oreille si il y a un objet direct (le pronom élidé *l'*) ou non, a fortiori si ils prononcent déjà peu le son [*l*] : *J'aime mieux marcher jusqu'à'station Papineau* (Tremblay). J'ai le réflexe d'opposer, pour bien distinguer les deux cas, dans la *langue parlée uniquement* (au Québec) :

> Comme si y l'avait mangé
>  Comme si y'avait mangé [sans objet direct]

Dans l'exemple modifié *comme si il/s'il avait toujours su* (sans objet direct), on s'attendrait à trouver soit *c'est* le précédant, en absolu, ou *que + complément*, le suivant, et introduisant ce qu'il avait toujours su. Il y a le contexte, et un phénomène phonétique comme l'haplologie ne saurait détrôner le signifié.

---

En français moderne, écrit et de registre usuel, on emploie surtout l'élision (*s'il*). Autrement on en assume le choix...

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Dit le LBU14 (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot) qu'on lira avec intérêt aux §§ 44 et 219, présentant les exemples des auteurs cités ici, et la nuance centrale du registre.</sub>